# How to make a function a memoized version of it in racket

Tags: racket, memoization

I am trying to define a make-memoize function that has a function f as argument. The idea is that make-memoize would return a procedure f that runs with memoization. I have been able to return a procedure after defining make-memoize with the function f as parameter. However, I haven't been able to actually apply the function to say add, subtract or multiply a number. ie. If I apply make-memoize with add-one function as parameter to number 28, I should get 29 as the result.

Here is what I got so far:

```
(define (make-memoize f)
  (let ((memoized-values (make-hash)))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (hash-has-key? memoized-values n)
          (hash-ref memoized-values n)
          (f n)))))
```

When I run make-memoize with the function add-one to 28:

```
(make-memoize (add-one 28))
```

This is what I get:

```
> (make-memoize (slow-add-one 28))
#<procedure:...s/rack-folder/test-file.rkt:26:4>
```

It seems to be throwing me the procedure and its directory? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error seems to be on line 26, column 4. What is on line 26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues:

- You don't update the hash table with the computed value
- `make-memoize` is a function which create a new function from a function

So the proper use is something like this:

```
(define (add-one n)
  (+ n 1))

(let ((fast-add-one (make-memoize add-one)))
  (fast-add-one 1)
  (fast-add-one 1)
  (fast-add-one 1))
```

The full code is available below, could be executed from `Racket IDE`:

```
(define (add-one n)
  (+ n 1))

(define (make-memoize f)
  (let ((memoized-values (make-hash)))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (hash-has-key? memoized-values n)
          ;; Get and return the value from hash-table
          (let ((previous-value (hash-ref memoized-values n)))
            (printf "READ VALUE ~A->~A~%" n previous-value)
            previous-value)
          ;; Update the value in the hash table
          (let ((new-value  (f n)))
            (printf "SET  VALUE ~A->~A~%" n new-value)
            (hash-set! memoized-values n new-value)
            new-value)))))

(let ((fast-add-one (make-memoize add-one)))
  (fast-add-one 1)
  (fast-add-one 1)
  (fast-add-one 1))
```

The result of the evaluation should be the following:

```
SET  VALUE 1->2 ;; Here, this is the first computation of add-one
READ VALUE 1->2 ;; Here, we just read from hash table
READ VALUE 1->2 ;; Here, we just read from hash table
```

EDIT: the answer to your *error* question

```
> (make-memoize (slow-add-one 28))
#<procedure:...s/rack-folder/test-file.rkt:26:4>
```

This is not an error, the `Racket` interpreter just return a `procedure` (a function) which is defined in the given filename/line.

In the code I provided, the function call `(make-memoize add-one))` also returns a `procedure`.

```
> (make-memoize add-one))
#<procedure>
```

Comment: Awesome Robert, thank you so much. I was also a bit confused with how to correctly use the function that make-memoize was returning. But now it makes more sense.

Comment: Note that your approach of `let`-binding to the memoized procedure will not work for recursive procedures. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common uses of memoization is to reduce computation in recursive procedure calls. Even when fixed up the posted code alone will not allow this. Further, binding a procedure created with `make-memoize` to a new identifier will have no effect since the un-memoized procedure is still used in all of the recursive calls.

As for the original posted code, given some key, the goal is to update the hash table with a new key unless that key is already found in the table (indicating that the calculation has already been made *and stored*. If the key is not found, then a value should be calculated for the key, and the results stored in the table. In either case, the value associated with the key should be returned.

This is a very literal transcription of what was just described:

```
(define (memo f)
  (let ((lookup (make-hash)))
    (lambda (x)
      (unless (hash-has-key? lookup x)
        (hash-set! lookup x (f x)))
      (hash-ref lookup x))))
```

Here, `memo` returns a procedure that, when called with `x`, checks `lookup` for the key `x`. If `x` is not found, it is added to `lookup` and associated with the value of `(f x)`. Finally, the value associated with `x` is returned.

### `let`-Binding Only Works for Limited Cases

When the `memo`-ized procedure is recursive, the desired effect is not obtained. Each recursive call uses `f`, not the `memo`-ized version of `f`, so there are no further lookups beyond the initial call. For example, given:

```
(define (fibonacci n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (else (+ (fibonacci (- n 2))
                 (fibonacci (- n 1))))))
```

This will not work as desired:

```
(let ((fast-fib (memo fibonacci)))
  (fast-fib 40))
```

Here `fast-fib` is bound to the `memo`-ized procedure, but `fibonacci` is invoked for the recursive calls, since that is how `fibonacci` is defined. This will not work either:

```
(let ((fibonacci (memo fibonacci)))
  (fibonacci 40))
```

Here `fibonacci` is rebound to the `memo`-ized procedure, but `fibonacci` called the *original* version of `fibonacci` at the time of definition, and continues to do so.

You need to find a way to change the definition of `fibonacci` so that it is itself the `memo`-ized procedure. You can do this by using `set!`. You could just evaluate `(set! fibonacci (memo fibonacci))` before using `fibonacci`. It would be nicer to have a macro which does this for you:

```
(define-syntax-rule (memoize! f)
  (set! f (memo f)))
```

This is a very simple macro that simply redefines the given procedure so that it is `memo`-ized. Here are some examples comparing the failed approaches with the successful approach:

```
memoize.rkt> (time (fibonacci 40))
cpu time: 2780 real time: 2780 gc time: 0
102334155

memoize.rkt> (time (let ((fast-fib (memo fibonacci))) (fast-fib 40)))
cpu time: 2800 real time: 2800 gc time: 1
102334155

memoize.rkt> (time (let ((fibonacci (memo fibonacci))) (fibonacci 40)))
cpu time: 2789 real time: 2789 gc time: 0
102334155

memoize.rkt> (memoize! fibonacci)

memoize.rkt> (time (fibonacci 40))
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
102334155
```

From the above you can see that the failed approaches have not improved the run time of the `fibonacci` procedure at all; in fact it appears that these incorrectly memoized versions are a little bit *slower* than the naked calls to `fibonacci`. This is because of the extra overhead incurred by calling `memo` on `fibonacci`, which creates a pointlessly memoized version that is called *only on the initial call* (all subsequent calls are really calling the naked `fibonacci` procedure). But the successfully memoized version calls *itself* on recursive calls, and it shows quite a lot of improvement.

To underscore the value of memoization, and the penalty for getting it wrong, consider `(fibonacci 45)`. This seems like a small increase over the previous `(fibonacci 40)`:

```
memoize.rkt> (time (let ((fast-fib (memo fibonacci))) (fast-fib 45)))
cpu time: 31042 real time: 31042 gc time: 11
1134903170

memoize.rkt> (memoize! fibonacci)

memoize.rkt> (time (fibonacci 45))
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
1134903170
```

And since the properly memoized version caches results between calls, I restarted the REPL for this next test:

```
memoize.rkt> (memoize! fibonacci)

memoize.rkt> (time (fibonacci 1000))
cpu time: 1 real time: 1 gc time: 0
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
```

The `fast-fib` version took almost 3 seconds to calculate `(fast-fib 40)`, and 31 seconds to calculate `(fast-fib 45)`. That is an order-of-magnitude slowdown for merely increasing the input value by 5. However, the properly memoized version of `fibonacci` took less than 1 microsecond to calculate `(fibonacci 40)`, less than 1 microsecond again to calculate `(fibonacci 45)`, and about 1 microsecond to calculate `(fibonacci 1000)` (starting from an empty `lookup` table in all three cases; performance is even better when calling `fibonacci` multiple times without clearing the cache). You would be waiting a very, very long time for `(fast-fib 1000)` to complete.

There are a lot of ways that this could be improved; you might want to be able to memoize procedures of more than one argument, or you might want to be able to clear the lookup table for a memoized procedure, or you might want to be able to un-memoize a procedure, etc. There is quite a lot of literature about memoization stretching back at least to the 1960s for anyone who wants to delve deeper. This particular topic of creating a memoized procedure from another procedure is called *automatic memoization*. [Here is a paper by Peter Norvig that includes a nice discussion of the technique](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238668053_Techniques_for_automatic_memoization_with_applications_to_context-free_parsing); note that this paper uses Common Lisp as the implementation language.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is part of the topics we are covering right now. Improving the code to memoize procedures of more than one argument is something we will cover soon.