# Set! on memoize and define something to memoize, difference?

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I have made this memoize function bellow and I am experimenting with it.

```
(define (make-table)
  (list '*table*))

(define (lookup key table)
  (let ((record (assoc key (cdr table)))) 
    (and record (cdr record))))

(define (insert! key value table)
  (let ((record (assoc key (cdr table))))
    (if record
        (set-cdr! record value)
        (set-cdr! table
                 (cons (cons key value) (cdr table))))))

(define (fib n)
  (display "computing fib of ")
  (display n) (newline)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (else (+ (fib (- n 1))
             (fib (- n 2))))))

(define (memoize message f)

  (define (dispatch message)
    (cond 
      ((eq? message 'memoize) memo)
      ((eq? message 'unmemoize) fibe)))

  (define memo 
    (let ((table (make-table)))
      (lambda (x)
        (let ((previously-computed-result (lookup x table)))
          (or previously-computed-result
              (let ((result (f x)))
                (insert! x result table)
                result)
               )))))

  (dispatch message) )
```

You can ignore the 'unmemoize) fibee part.

What I have a hard time understanding is why these two lines of codes bellow don't act in the same way.

```
(set! fib(memoize 'memoize  fib))
```

and

```
(define mm (memoize 'memoize fib))
```

fib here is this function:

```
(define (fib n)
(cond ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= n 1) 1)
      (else (+ (fib (- n 1))
               (fib (- n 2))))))
```

Calling these functions bellow gives me different results and I don't understand why

```
(fib 3)
(fib 3)
(mm 3)
(mm 3)
```

Result:

calling (fib 3) twice:
[image]

calling (mm 3 ) twice and (mm 2) once
[image]

As you can see (mm 3) and (fib 3) act differently, and when I run (mm 2) I don't see why we don't just get the number 1 as return but new computation

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? Did you delete the previous version?

Comment: @amalloy Yes, I believe I did not offer enough information for the last one.

Comment: "_Calling these functions below gives me different results and I don't understand why._" -- What are those different results?

Comment: @adabsurdum I posted the results

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]: where are definitions for  `make-table`, `lookup`, `insert!`? Remove `((eq? message 'unmemoize) fibe)` if it is not relevant. Is this `#lang racket`?

Comment: @adabsurdum Okei i will now put the whole needed code in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `(define mm (memoize 'memoize fib))`, `mm` calls a memoized *version* of `fib`, but `fib` itself is defined to recursively call itself, and `fib` is *not* memoized. That is, when `mm` is called, only the initial call to `fib` is subject to memoization.

This can be seen by using a `trace` functionality. It appears that the posted code is not Racket, but instead `#lang r5rs`, which allows access to Racket's `trace` procedure with `(#%require racket/trace)`. We can use this to see the calls to `fib` as they unfold. Note that I commented out the `display` calls in OP definition of `fib` to remove some noise in the output:

```
bad-memo.rkt> (#%require racket/trace)
bad-memo.rkt> (trace fib)
bad-memo.rkt> (fib 5)
>(fib 5)
> (fib 4)
> >(fib 3)
> > (fib 2)
> > >(fib 1)
< < <1
> > >(fib 0)
< < <0
< < 1
> > (fib 1)
< < 1
< <2
> >(fib 2)
> > (fib 1)
< < 1
> > (fib 0)
< < 0
< <1
< 3
> (fib 3)
> >(fib 2)
> > (fib 1)
< < 1
> > (fib 0)
< < 0
< <1
> >(fib 1)
< <1
< 2
<5
5
```

This produces *exactly the same trace*, which I will omit here to save space:

```
bad-memo.rkt> (define mm (memoize 'memoize fib))
bad-memo.rkt> (mm 5)
;; --> same output as `(fib 5)` above
```

When `mm` is called the memoized version of `fib` is called once, and then the *unmemoized* `fib` is called many times.

With `(set! fib (memoize 'memoize  fib))` things are different. This time `memoize` returns a memoized version of `fib`, and the symbol `fib` is mutated so that it refers to this memoized version! Now whenever `fib` is called, it is the memoized version that is called, and this includes recursive calls:

```
bad-memo.rkt> (set! fib (memoize 'memoize fib))
bad-memo.rkt> (fib 5)
>(fib 5)
> (fib 4)
> >(fib 3)
> > (fib 2)
> > >(fib 1)
< < <1
> > >(fib 0)
< < <0
< < 1
< <2
< 3
<5
5
```

Here you can see the difference by comparing the trace for `fib` before and after setting it to the memoized version.

For some further reading, [here is a related answer that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304604/6879826) some time ago.

Comment: Thank you for making this clearer for me and suggesting trace. This was very helpfull